# Параметр "форма" должен содержать допустимую форму Django

Tags: python, html, django

Учусь Django по книге. Код идентичен коду из книги. Фрагмент HTML кода:

```
{% block searchform %}
{% endblock %}
<form>
    {% bootstrap_form form show_label=False %}
    {% bootstrap_button content='Поиск' button_type='submit' %}
</form>
```

Код самой формы:

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    keyword = forms.CharField(required=False, max_length=20, label='')
```

Код контроллер класса:

```
def by_hashtag(request, pk):
    hashtag = get_object_or_404(Hashtag, pk=pk)
    a = Articles.objects.filter(is_active=True, hashtag=pk)
    if 'keyword' in request.GET:
        keyword = request.GET['keyword']
        q = Q(title__icontans=keyword) | Q(text__icontans=keyword)
        a = a.filter(q)
    else:
        keyword = ''
    form = SearchForm(initial={'keyword': keyword})
    paginator = Paginator(a, 2)
    if 'page' in request.GET:
        page_num = request.GET['page']
    else:
        page_num = 1
    page = paginator.get_page(page_num)
    context = {'hashtag': hashtag, 'page': page, 'a': page.object_list, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'main/by_hashtag.html', context)
```

Выдает ошибку: "Parameter "form" should contain a valid Django Form." Проверял пытался гуглить ничего не получается. Подскажите в чем может быть проблема.

Comment: https://evileg.com/ru/forum/topic/1601/

Comment: Пробовал, формы не выводятся, только кнопка "поиск"

Answer (score 0):

У вас написано. Параметр "form" должен содержать валидную Django Form.
Попробуйте валидировать форму

```
....
    if form.is_valid():
        print("yes")
.....
```